# Wordpress - Admin Menu - Sub Sub Page?

Tags: wordpress, oop, menu, admin, children

I've added custom menus to the admin menu in the backend, and I almost always have sub pages, but is it possible to have a 3rd level of page, or "sub sub menu pages"?

Snippet of code:

```
add_action('admin_menu',array(new mmr_menu((isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : "mmr")),'mk_menu'));

class mmr_menu{
    public function mk_menu(){

        add_menu_page('MMR', 'MMR', 'administrator', PLUGIN_PREFIX.'mmr', array(&$this,'get_page'), PLUGIN_DIR.'inc/images/logo.gif');

        add_submenu_page(PLUGIN_PREFIX.'mmr', PLUGIN_PREFIX.'app_and_reg', 'Applications & Registrations', 'administrator', PLUGIN_PREFIX.'app_and_reg', array(&$this,"get_page"));

        // Doesn't work
        add_submenu_page(PLUGIN_PREFIX.'app_and_reg', PLUGIN_PREFIX.'payment_reports', 'Payments', 'administrator', PLUGIN_PREFIX.'payment_reports', array(&$this,"get_page"));
    }
}
```

`PLUGIN_PREFIX` and `PLUGIN_DIR` are defines, and `mmr_menu->get_page()` is a public method that I didn't think was necessary to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually plugin authors create tabs for 3rd level pages. These are not registered as seperate pages, but you can add a query arg to select the page, and link to the different tabs that way.
Example:

```
<?php
function payment_reports() {

    // first, lets print out the tabs ?>
    <ul class="tabs">
         <a href="[sub-page url]&tab=first">Tab 1</a>
         <a href="[sub-page url]&tab=second">Tab 2</a>
         <a href="[sub-page url]&tab=third">Tab 3</a>
    </ul><?php

    switch ($_GET['tab']) {
        case 'second':
            output_first_tab();
            break;
        case 'third':
            output_first_tab();
            break;
        default:
            output_first_tab();
    }


}

?>
```

Having said that, some wordpress frameworks (link piklist) have support for 3rd level tabs built in

Comment: I noticed the tab thing after I asked the question, but I usually see jQuery tabs. I also wasn't aware that some frameworks supported this. Since I never answered this question with my own tabs response, I'll accept this one.